# Indent region in python script

Tags: indentation, python

I have some lines of code in a python script opened under `Py Outl` mode:

```
last=-1
for i in range(len(page_nos)-1, -1, -1):
    if page_nos[i] != 'NULL':
        last = i
        break

if last == -1:                                                                                
    page_nos[0] = 1
    last = 0
```

I want to put them into a function, so I add a line of function definition in front of them:

```
def fillnull(page_nos):

last=-1
for i in range(len(page_nos)-1, -1, -1):
    if page_nos[i] != 'NULL':
        last = i
        break

if last == -1:                                                                              
    page_nos[0] = 1
    last = 0
```

I then want to indent the original lines so that they can become the body of the function. By selecting the region and `M-x indent-region`, the region becomes:

```
def fillnull(page_nos):

    last=-1
    for i in range(len(page_nos)-1, -1, -1):
        if page_nos[i] != 'NULL':
            last = i
            break

        if last == -1: 
            page_nos[0] = 1
            last = 0
```

Why does it put extra indents in front of the second if block?

How can I indent the original lines correctly? Thanks.

Comment: You can use indent-rigidly (C-x TAB) to indent the region by a fixed amount. Not sure about the mode-specific indent behavior you are seeing though.

Comment: How do you enter (C-x TAB) ? M-x indent-rigidly is sole completion.

Comment: select region & then do, `M-x indent-rigidly`

Comment: @Mad: that only put a space in front of each line

Comment: Sorry, the command is indent-rigidly. By default it is bound to the key sequence Ctrl-x followed by <tab>. You can call the command either way, then use the arrow keys to adjust the indent level.

Comment: when i tried Tim's example, doing `indent-rigidly` put one space. now, i want to remove it. with the selected region, i pressed `Shift + tab`, it didn't erase the indent? how to unindent?

Comment: @glucas: thanks. but after c-x tab,   "use the arrow keys to adjust the indent level" doesn't work.

Comment: What version of emacs are you using? The other way to specify how far to indent is a prefix argument. For example type `C-8 M-x indent-region` to indent 8 spaces.

Comment: @glucas: one of the most recent versions. C-8 M-x indent-region not working, because C-8 will erase the selected region.  How can I repeat M-x indent-rigidly for 4 times?

Comment: C-8 means Ctrl-8. This is a standard way to provide a number argument to a command. Indent-rigidly takes such an argument to decide how far to indent. I am using emacs 24.4 -- for me, calling indent-rigidly without a prefix argument enters an interactive mode where the left/right arrows adjust the indent level further.

Comment: @glucas: I know C means Ctrl. I said C-8 will erase the selected region immediately before I can type M-x ....

Comment: I don't see that behavior in any mode. Guess I can't help further other than steer you to the emacs manual section on prefix args and use C-h f indent-rigidly for the command doc.

Comment: If C-8 is doing something else in this py mode you can also specify a prefix arg in other ways, eg M-8. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html for more.

Comment: @Tim Try out the rigid indentation as glucas mentioned in an "emacs -Q" session.

Comment: @glucas: thanks. What if I need to reduce indent of a region by 4 spaces?

Comment: A negative prefix will reduce the indent. Eg M-- M-4 C-x <tab>.

Answer (score 3):

Caused as `py-indent-region` calculated indent of every single line. Which results in outmost indent of each line.

As this may destroy program-logic, fixed in trunk following

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1426903

New behavior:

If first line of regions indent is changed, remaining lines' indent is kept by default.

If first lines' indent is unchanged, the remaining are calculated line-by-line, also With C-u option.

Comment: Thanks. how can I fix my emacs problem?